# Selenium WebDriverWait or implicitly_wait are waiting more time than expected

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium with Python and Chromedriver, and i want to take a screenshot of browser when a exception is ocurred. I've tried doing it with WebDriverWait with the following code:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
except TimeoutException:
    driver.save_screenshot(Config.screenshot_path)
```

The problem is when the current page of browser is loading, the driver waits until the page load to keep going and take the screenshot. I need the screenshot to be taken exactly when timeout has ocurred, not when page is loaded.

Also i tried with `implicitly_wait` but the result is the same, the driver waits until page is loaded to procceed doing anything.

I also set the pageLoadStrategy as "none" like the following:

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = webdriver_path, chrome_options = options , desired_capabilities = caps)
```

I've also tried with `driver.set_page_load_timeout(timeout)` but nothing changes as i'm not using `get()` to load the page, i'm only searching for an element.

I want to know if there's a way to make the driver not wait until page is loaded but continue with execution after the timeout time.

Another thing i tried was to put a `time.sleep(1)` before the screenshot method, but still the driver waits for the page to being loaded.

Comment: If you want to take a screenshot after a certain time elapses, you can probably some sort of timer to take the screenshot. If you want the page to load after the exception, you will need to call `WebDriverWait` again with a longer timeout.

Comment: I think your code is correct. But why you use `self.driver` in WebDriverWait but `driver` in TimeoutException.

Comment: As @Mike67 suggested, i tried with time.sleep(1) but the problem still is there, the driver waits for the page loaded.

Comment: @Yun My bad when trancribing from my code to SO, question edited.

Answer (score 0):

### Change the implicit wait of the driver

It might add additional seconds because of the implicit wait you set to the driver, do this:

```py
driver.implicit_wait(1) # or 0
```

The reason is because if you look at the `presence_of_element_located` function you will find out it is using the `driver.find_element`:

```py
def presence_of_element_located(locator):
    """ An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM
    of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.
    locator - used to find the element
    returns the WebElement once it is located
    """

    def _predicate(driver):
        return driver.find_element(*locator)

    return _predicate
```

And `driver.find_element` will not return a result till the implicit wait limit hits

### Suggestion

By using `driver.find_elements` this is the fastest way to check if an element exist without using any implicit or explicit waits, it will return a list of web driver element objects but will return a empty list so quickly if there was not any elements with the given selector.

Where you can do this:

```py
def wait_element(by: By, value: str, timeout: int):

  for i in range(timeout):
    found = driver.find_elements(by, value)
    if found:
      return
    sleep(1)
  raise TimeoutError(f"Could not find element {by}={value}")
```